# PHP Jquery ajax class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, frameworks

I have been using [xajax](http://xajaxproject.org), as a server side ajax class (all the ajax *response* is handled with php code) for the longest while.

However I lately fell in love with jquery, and am using it for a project. I would like to know if there is a server side class (like xajax) that handles jquery ajax? or does anyone know of a tutorial/example i can use to create my own?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you read the docs for `$.ajax()`? [Check it out](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two alternatives:

1. http://phery-php-ajax.net/
2. https://github.com/spantaleev/sijax/

Updated link for phery library

Comment: Thank you, though you are a little late, these are what i have been looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jquery(javascript) is a frontend/public language.  Of course you will need to verify any data sent via javascript, on the server-side and/or both on the front-end.

jQuery has a plethora of options concerning ajax. ( $.post/$.get/$.getJSON/$.ajax ). these send/retrieve data via a HTTP request.

If you have leaned towards jQuery, why would you want a php-ajax library?  You will do your input validating server-side anyway!

jquery/ajax will send your data either with a post or get request, you just grab it with php and verify.

For a user-friendly experience I would suggest both frontend/backend validating.

Comment: So i can manage the stuff from the server side. Thanks for the info though.